# Nothing changed (missing files, see hg status) when comitting

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I mapped to a drive an ftp, I went and did `hg init`

then added a file, did `hg add` then `hg commit -u username -m 'message'`

I am getting the message `nothing changed (2 missing files, see hg status)`

hg status return this:

```
X:\public_html>hg status
A .htaccess
A index.html
```

I can't seem to find someone else remotely close to my problem and official doc didn't help me either.

I'm out of ideas, every bit of information is appreciated.

Comment: using the -A option worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems incredibly unlikely this is going to work on a FTP mapped drive.  Version control systems rely on coherent filesystem primitives (lock counts, etc.) that your mapping software likely doesn't fake correctly enough.  Mercurial has its own protocol for moving changes to/from a computer (push and pull over HTTP or SSH) and that's the right way to get stuff to and from the machine on which the FTP server is running.

That said, you might have a small bit of luck with:

```
hg commit -u username -m 'message' .htaccess index.html
```

if the problem is commit not detecting the files as modified/added.

It looks like the server you're FTPing to/from is a linux box, so it's already running sshd.  That means you can clone to it with:

```
hg clone c:\localclone ssh://you@there//full/path/to/repo
```

and can push/pull from that URL as well.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will proceed to ditch my current host, and get a new host with mercurial pre-installed  as I have passed enough time on this issue.

Comment: You can get a free server over which you have total control for a year at amazon.  I've no idea why I see people paying for these shared hosting platforms they don't have control over.